# Убрать стили css в head, которые показываются исходным кодом браузера

Tags: css, wordpress

В исходном коде браузера в блоке `head` показывается `css` код:

```
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-image: url('http://ali-coupons.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ali-background.png'); background-repeat: repeat; background-position: top left; background-attachment: scroll; }
</style>
```

В `header.php` эти стили не указаны. Никак не пойму как сделать так, чтобы он ушёл оттуда.
Сайт на `WordPress 4.4.4`.

Comment: посмотрите в fucntions.php или если есть настройки темы то в админке

Comment: Ничего там такого в fucntions.php я не нашёл. Ребята, кто-то может посоветовать что-то?

Answer (score 1):

http://wp-kama.ru/function/add_theme_support#custom-background

Закомментируйте в файле `functions.php` вашей темы `add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );` чтобы получилось `// add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );`.

Или же удалите из перечисления к примеру:
Из `add_theme_support( 'custom-background', 'post-thumbnail', 'custom-header' );`
чтобы получилось `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnail', 'custom-header' );`.